# Bootstrap 3 navbar collapsing to two lines instead of shrinking images

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This looks great:

http://imageshack.us/a/img96/5789/n4u7.png

But when you shrink another 5 pixels, the columns appear to break and the image goes to a new line.

http://imageshack.us/a/img59/2195/uk4v.png

Instead, I would like the image to shrink, so it can stay on the same line as the collapsible button.

The HTML:

```
  <!-- navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <!-- container -->
      <div class="container">
        <!-- navbar header -->
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/img/logo.png" >
            </a>
          </div>
          <!-- /navbar header -->
          <!-- collapse -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse navbar-right">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!-- /collapse -->
        </div>
    <!-- container -->
  </nav>
  <!-- /navbar -->
```

The CSS:

```
    nav.navbar {
      padding-top: 0;
      padding-bottom: 0;
      background: rgba(179, 153, 255, .5)
    }

    nav.navbar div.container {
      background: rgba(179, 153, 255, 1.0);
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

    a.navbar-brand {
      padding: 0 0 20px 15px;
    }

    img.img-responsive {
      width: 100%;
    }

    @media (min-width: 992px) {
        ul.navbar-nav li a {
            padding-top: 12px;
            padding-bottom: 12px;
            border-top: 2px solid white;
            border-bottom: 2px solid white;
          margin-top: 36px;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you expect it to do at that point? You have two elements with a total width larger than the display. It can wrap, cut-off the overflowing content, or have the two elements be on top of each other. What is your expectation?

Comment: I would like the image to shrink instead of breaking to a new line.

Comment: Then you will need to add some `@media` query for xsmall devices, to have something like `.navbar-brand img { max-width: 80%; }`

Comment: Doesn't fix it. It shrinks the image but the navbar-brand element remains the same size as if the image were never shrunk. I really need the fixed navbar to not change its size because then it messes up the top of the body.

Comment: can you provide a link to the image? and uhm... you can always set a `min-width` to avoid getting to that level... but if i have ur image i can probably work on something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the image to shrink when you make the viewport smaller, the width of the image's containing element needs to be set as a percentage. In this case the image's immediate containing element is the anchor, so if you set that anchor width of 60% or whatever works, then when the viewport shrinks, the anchor width will shrink to maintain its 60% of its container, and the image with its width of 100% of the anchor will also shrink. Anchor will need to have block level display too.